# Emphasized Wrinkles, Freckles, and Dark Spots

Tags: photoshop

Is there a name in photography postprocessing for this kind of look?

[http://s-magazine.photography/ceemes/article/show/698/page=285/layout=588/**language**=en](http://s-magazine.photography/ceemes/article/show/698/page=285/layout=588/__language__=en)

[http://s-magazine.photography/ceemes/article/show/640/page=285/layout=588/**language**=en](http://s-magazine.photography/ceemes/article/show/640/page=285/layout=588/__language__=en)

How can it be achieved?

There are other photos of this sort, but I can't find them right now.

Comment: Possible terms for search engines: "high contrast" and [Richard Avedon](http://www.americansuburbx.com/2011/01/richard-avedon-richard-avedons-in.html) look. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't know what post-processing software you use, but I use the Clarity slider in Adobe Camera Raw to achieve the contrasty, gritty look you show. The more you slide to the right, the heavier the effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is called local contrast and micro-contrast enhancement, and many software tools call it "Clarity" or "Detail". E.g. see the Topaz Clarity [showcase](https://www.topazlabs.com/clarity).